# Import csv product does not show on frontend in magento

Tags: php, magento, csv

I have a csv with two products when I import this csv from admin panel it shows import successful and this product is shown on under manage categories with position 1.

This product is not visible on my shop.

When I change position 1 to 0 and save it and refresh all it will be display on frontend.

or when I go product management and save this product without change it will display on frontend.

I read about something refresh indexing but in my developer Magento I didn't find this option

any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under System->Index Management
Select all and in dropdown select Reindex option and submit it.