# Import products not show on frontend page

Tags: magento

After import a product with CSV file, you can not see this product on the frontend page.
So I saw this question but I can not answer on this because I have not enough reputation points. [Question already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110900/import-csv-product-does-not-show-on-frontend-in-magento)

If I going to 'System->Index Management Select all and in dropdown select Reindex option and submit' I can not see the function Reindex but only 'Update on save' and 'Update by schedule'.

So are they more people with this issue?

//update
I tried to reindex with the terminal and there's an error

```
  [Exception]                                                                  
  Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJ  
  NDAEL_256' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Magentooo/vendor/magento/framework/  
  Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 394
```

Answer (score 0):

In magento2 index management facility is not available from admin area.If you have selected Update on save then re-indexing will be performed when a product is being saved.

In-order to re-index data manually as per need then login via ssh and navigate to your magento root directory and execute command given below:-

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex